# Parallel delaunay triangulation

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, triangulation, delaunay, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to parallelize the [Guibas Stolfi delaunay triangulation](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~gl/research/comp_geom/delaunay/delaunay.html) using **openmp**.

There are two things to parallelize here-
the **mergesort()**,which i did and 
the **divide()** where I am stuck.
I have tried all possible approaches but in vain.

The approach followed(divide n conquer) in divide() is same as that of mergesort(),but applying the same parallelization technique(omp sections) works only for mergesort.

I tried the [parallelization technique shown here](http://code.google.com/p/dewall-omp/),but even that doesn't work.
I read about nested parallelism somewhere but i am not sure how to implement it.
Can anybody explain how divide and conquer algorithms are parallelized?

**CODE:Called mergesort twice in main function and applied sections construct.Doing same for divide function doesn't work**

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp sections nowait
{
#pragma omp section
{
merge_sort(p_sorted, p_temp, 0, n/2);
}
#pragma omp section
{
merge_sort(p_sorted, p_temp, (n/2)+1, n-1);
}
}
}
```

Comment: find entire code:-http://pastebin.com/4nxbAts7

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in parallelizing using the CreateThread calls in Windows, the trick is to divide the points into 2^n buffers, process each buffer in a separate thread and then merge adjacent edges, successively, until one final merge.

I have a demonstation program to create random data and triangulate and display the results (for smaller cases).  It doesn't look like this site lets me download the .zip I have of the program and display tool.  If you can suggest an upload site or provide an email I'll send it to you.

Comment: mail me at getanshub4u[AT]gmail[dot]com